# Log base 2 in keynote

Tags: iwork-keynote

I want a logarithmic scale on my scatter chart's x axis. When I use log scale in keynote, it uses log base 10, with no option for changing the base.

Does keynote support log base 2? If not, is there a workaround for adding custom x tics?